# How can I hide 0.00 rate estimate if free shipping

Tags: magento2, php

I am creating custom shipping module in Magento 2. How can I hide $0.00 if there is no shipping price. Can I pass alternative text or hide this value?

[image]

Comment: Can manage with jQuery?